# Reporting different url for cloned site

Tags: javascript, apache

I've got an internet site, `http://MIRRORED_SITE.com`, mirrored on my local computer running apache at, `http://CLONED.com`.

Looking at the source code of the pages at `http://CLONED.com`, I can see instances `http://CLONED.com` getting generated by javascript instead of `http://MIRRORED_SITE.com`. This interferes with the proper functioning of other javascript code. Here's an exmaple:

`<link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=CLONED.com" as="script">`

I'm looking for one of two solutions, whichever might be easiest:

1) Modify the local files by injecting some bit of javascript into the html so that `http://MIRRORED_SITE.com` shows inside the source code instead.

2) Alternatively, I'm wondering if there might be some trick I could use in apache that could substitute all instances of `http://CLONED.com` with `http://MIRRORED_SITE.com`. This is probably trickier since the url is generated client side.

UPDATE: A third option, which I have already done, is to modify my vhosts file and /etc/hosts file so `http://MIRRORED_SITE.com` is pulled up locally. I'd like to avoid this solution because then I can't access the MIRRORED site unless I modify my config files back to the original configuration.

Thanks!

Comment: Depends where those url's are used and if they exist in static files or can be set user server side code. If it is just to fix links...that's simple. For resource files like img, css etc is a bit different

Comment: The url's are generated by the javascript in the page. I confirmed this by running the site under the MIRRORED_SITE domain locally. Everything works perfectly when I run the site like this.

Comment: So fixing the javascript would be easy. Show example. Also be specific. Is that server side javascript(node.js) or javascript sent to browser?

Comment: Note that in browser : `window.location.hostname` gives you domain page is on. So a simple `getBaseUrl()` function could be used to replace hard code values

Comment: I'm not sure if it's node.js or not. I know how to program but I know very little js beyond dropping code between <script> tags.

Comment: These aren't hard-coded values. They are generated by javascript and the appear in a string: `<link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=CLONED.com" as="script">`

Comment: Ok well that is completely different then. That request doesn't even go through your server...it goes to google's

Comment: So that `<link>` tag is probably hard coded in your `<head>` is it?

Comment: Yeah, I need to change that CLONED.com to the original site. It appears in about 30 different places within the HTML. Figured there's got to be an easy way to do this with javascript. I know it can be done because when I archive a page locally using the built-in "save" feature in the browser, it shows as MIRRORED_SITE.com

Comment: No, there is no <link> tag. My URL is not in the HTML at all. CLONED.com is getting generated by other js on the page using window.location.href or something else that tells js what the domain is.

Comment: Hard to help without seeing some code

Comment: There is no code except a giant HTML document sitting on my local server. That's not going to help you. I just need the server or HTML page to report that the domain is MIRRORED_SITE.com

Comment: As I tried to explain in my OP, if I change my apache settings so that the site is called MIRRORED_SITE.com and change my /etc/hosts file so that 127.0.0.1 points to MIRRORED_SITE.com, I will see MIRRORED_SITE in the generated HTML like I want.

Comment: This guy is trying to do the same thing I'm doing. He's using a reverse proxy. I think I'm going to try that: https://benjaminhorn.io/code/apache-reverse-proxy/